# Is the targetSize property of Graticule meant to be dynamically updatable?

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers v6.3.1

I create a Map and add an OSM TileLayer() and a Graticule to it. Graticule created via:

```
var graticule = new Graticule({
  // the style to use for the lines, optional.
  strokeStyle: new Stroke({
    color: "blue",
    width: 2
  }),
  showLabels: false,
  wrapX: false,
  targetSize: 30
});
```

If I have a slider on my UI that I want to control the size of the grid displayed, can I dynamically modify graticule.targetSize with it's value ? I've tried and it doesn't work. Not sure if that's by design or it is a bug.

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/graticule-rby9m

Note - I always have to hit the reload button the first time I load the sandbox above; not sure why.

Regards and thanX -

Comment: There would be a setTargefSize() method if it was updatable.  But can can remove and recreate the graticule to produce the same effect https://codesandbox.io/s/graticule-nzcnv

Comment: Thank you @Mike. I will try and use that. I did think about it but thought it was a bit clunky - but if it works; better than nothing.